# Windows Hello for Business is crashing my PC, please tell me how to fix

Tags: windows-10, freeze, crash, windows-hello

It is some time now that my PC freezes just after starting it up after a few hours of inactivity, after that initial freeze it goes all well. Checking the error registry I always find this one the moment before it freezes:

> Windows Hello for Business provisioning will not be launched.  Device
>   is AAD joined ( AADJ or DJ++ ): Not Tested  User has logged on with
>   AAD credentials: No  Windows Hello for Business policy is enabled: Not
>   Tested  Local computer meets Windows hello for business hardware
>   requirements: Not Tested  User is not connected to the machine via
>   Remote Desktop: Yes  User certificate for on premise auth policy is
>   enabled: Not Tested  Machine is governed by none policy.  See
>   https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=832647 for more details.

The service is unavailable/inactive on my PC since it is a desktop and not a laptop and I dont have devices for biometrics login procedures.

**Update**: it just happened again while using the PC, not right after startup like usually, I was opening a picture using system default photo program (not paint 3d, I think it is called just "Photo")

**Update 2**: PC just freeze again, this time I was doing nothing, just moving the mouse on the desktop, joined Group Home domain and added Microsoft account as a way to login into my PC.

Comment: does it freeze for precisely 30, 60, or 90 seconds? These are typical hardware timeout periods (i.e. it is waiting for something that does not happen and then gives up)

Comment: @Yorik it freezes until I power off unfortunately. No sound, mouse stuck, no response from keyboard.

Comment: Sounds like UWP application problem if it happened with Photo.  Do other UWP applications cause this problem?

Comment: @Ramhound Sorry but what is an UWP application?

Comment: [Google Search "UWP application"](https://www.google.com/#safe=off&q=UWP+application)

Comment: @Ramhound I'm not sure if Photo is an App for Windows, how do I check what program is the default for opening the pictures?

Comment: @Ritardi.Net - I am telling you it is.  Photos is the UWP application to view images, installed by default, unless remove by an Administrator and a new .wim image is generated.  How you view which program is configured to handle which file extension has remained unchanged between Windows 7, Windows 8, and Windows 10.

Comment: @Ramhound I'm not much fond of windows Apps, i was looking in the store a place to lookup all installed apps and to test if they are all causing this issue but could not find a list of installed UWP Apps. The one I found controls the camera and it is not causing this issue however.

Comment: There are tools built-in to Windows that already list errors. The Event Viewer, for instance. These will list issues with UWP programs just as surely as they will for other applications. There is no need to go to the Windows Store to look for such an application, especially as you note that you are not fond of Windows apps.

Comment: I am pretty sure Windows Hello functionality is based on the UWP though.  Which is the reason I suspect its a compatability problem with UWP applications if Photo also caused the program.  There are dozens of UWP applications installed by default unless you removed them, and if you removed them, it's possible those actions are the source of your problem.  Have you attemped to install a virgin Windows 10 ISO onto the system, joined the machine to your domain if you have one, then see if Windows Hello still causes a problem?

Comment: "No Windows Hello for Business policy is enabled" - indicates the Windows Hello group policy is disabled.

Comment: @music2myear,@Ramhound I looked up the event viewer and there is no trace of the last freeze (caused by photo app) I'm not sure how to join a domain on my machine, are you referring to group home? Also ins't Hello only used on laptops with biometric devices?